# How to create a categorical variable using union in SQL?

Tags: sql

If I have data like...

```
user_id user_revenue 
10000   100
10001   150
10002   175
10003   200
10004   250
10005   300
10006   400
10007   500
10007   550
```

I'm trying to transform the data into this using union:

```
user_id   user_revenue
10000      Low
10001      Low
10002      Low
10003      Medium
10004      Medium
10005      Medium
10006      High
10007      High
10007      High
```

Where "High" is when revenue is at least 400 and "medium" is less than 400 but greater than 175 then low is when the revenue is at most 175.

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple `CASE` statement on `user_revenue`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id,
CASE
    WHEN t.user_revenue > 400 THEN 'High'
    WHEN t.user_revenue > 175 THEN 'Medium'
    ELSE 'Low'
END AS user_revenue
FROM [Table] t;
```